# ASP.NET MVC Page not Updated when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript

I have an ASP.NET MVC project where I want to post an article to the database then display a snippet of the article on the page. When a user comments, I also want to display the comment once I have saved to the database. I am using AJAX for this and call `OnFailure` and `OnSuccess` methods in both cases.

The `OnFailure` method only fires up when I save a post and not a comment (this is because the page isn't updated even when I save successfully). The `OnSuccess` method isn't invoked at all which is because my page isn't updated.

I am using **jquery 2.1.4** and have **jquery.unobtrusive-ajax** script loaded in my project

Here is my code.

//View for creating a post

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Post",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    UpdateTargetId = "insertnewpostbelow",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    OnSuccess = "postingSucceeded()",
    OnFailure = "postingFailed()"
}))
 {
  //View code left out 
 }
```

//Server side for saving post and updating `PartialView`

```
 [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken, ValidateInput(false)]
    public async Task<PartialViewResult> Create
        ([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Message,PostedOn,isAbuse,By")] Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var list = new List<Post>();
            list.Add(post);

            try
            {
                db.Posts.Add(post);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                return PartialView("_Posts", list);
            }
            catch (RetryLimitExceededException)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to login, please try again and contact administrator if the problem persists.");

                //If we got this far, model has errors.
                ViewBag.By = new SelectList(db.Members, "ID", "FullNames", post.By);
                return PartialView("_Posts", post);
            }
        }

        //If we got this far, model has errors.
        ViewBag.By = new SelectList(db.Members, "ID", "FullNames", post.By);
        return PartialView("_Posts", post);
    }
```

//My JavaScript file

```
    function postingSucceeded() {
    alert("Posting succeeded.");
}

function postingFailed() {
    alert("Posting failured.");
}
```

//Portion of the View to update

```
<div id="big-posts">
        <span id="insertnewpostbelow"></span>

        @Html.Partial("_Posts", Model.Posts)
    </div>
```

What am I missing out, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need parenthesis in ajax.beginform parameters it should be `OnSuccess = "postingSucceeded", OnFailure = "postingFailed"`

Comment: Thanks @AlexArt for pointing that out. However after changing the code, my problem isn't fixed

Comment: can you share your partial view too.

Comment: @AlexArt. no difference.

Comment: @Dennis i need to see _Posts.cshtml can you share that

Comment: make sure you have one element on page with id that you are updating after ajax call

Comment: onFailure will fire when your ajax call failed (means some error occured in action)

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have an Ajax form in *_Posts* `PartialView`. After the placement, say, after `<span id="insertnewpostbelow"></span>` you need to run *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax* on page again.

**Note that** the scripts will render on page loads, not after any changes in page (like updates by `PartialView`).

**Solution:** call the script again, after the page update :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the content of the returned partial view somewhere on the page

```
<div id="big-posts">
   <span id="insertnewpostbelow"></span>
   <div id="newPost"></div>
</div>
```

On the call back function try:

```
function postingSucceeded(data) {
    $("#newPost").html(data);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

First thing you don't need to have **parenthesis**

```
OnSuccess = "postingSucceeded()"
                            ^^^

OnFailure = "postingFailed()"
                         ^^^
```

just

```
OnSuccess = "postingSucceeded",
OnFailure = "postingFailed"
```

and now **HTML code**

```
<div id="big-posts">
   <span id="insertnewpostbelow"></span>
   <div id="AppendPostsHere"></div>
</div>
```

and **javascript** code **out side** the `$(document).ready(....)`

```
function postingSucceeded(newPosts) {
    $("#AppendPostsHere").html(newPosts);
}
```

hope this willl work!